# How to store all values of column from input file in list

Tags: python, scripting, python-2.6

I want to store all column 2 values from input file to a list
so that i can pass those value as argument to another command in script.

As of now with current code, i get only last inserted value that is "2" in list(interface_list) and because of this i am able to pass only one value to another command.

Input file :

```
ipaddress,intefaceid
10.170.15.16,1
10.170.15.20,3
10.170.15.20,4
10.170.15.30,2
10.170.15.16,2
```

Code :

```
import csv
def load_interfaces(ip):
    f = open("ip_interface_map.csv", "r")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        if ip in line:
            interface_list = []
            interface_list.append(line[1])
            print interface_list
#        return interface_list
load_interfaces('10.170.15.16')
```

Comment: place `interface_list = []` outside the `for-loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get it done by placing the `interface_list = []` outside the for loop.

```
...
interface_list = []
for line in reader:
    if ip in line:
        interface_list.append(line[1])
        ...
```